# How to use Multithreading in Kafka

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka

I am trying to read kafka messages from producer using **Java Multithreading**.

Suppose, **Kafka Producer** send multiple messages to **Kafka Consumer**. then how to read those multiple messages seperatly using **ExecutorService in JAVA**

Comment: this is not a question about kafka more about how to use java executor service or multithreading api. The executor service you can use a Future or a Threadpool depending on your taste each thread can then subscribe to a topic and stream the messages. You should describe more what you really want to do.

Comment: This could be the best way to do it instead of using ExecutorService https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58889112/spring-kafkalistener-and-concurrency

Answer (score 4):

I have implemented your mentioned case and i am going to share steps that you should follow.

**Create a consumer class which must implement Runnable interface, it must have a Kafkaconsumer instance as a class member. You can configure consumer properties in constructor method.**

```
public LogConsumer(List<String> topics, String group, String brokerList) {

    Properties propsConsumer = new Properties();
    propsConsumer.put("bootstrap.servers", brokerList);
    propsConsumer.put("group.id", group);
    propsConsumer.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
    propsConsumer.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    propsConsumer.put("value.deserializer", ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
    propsConsumer.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");

    this.consumer = new KafkaConsumer(propsConsumer);
    this.consumer.subscribe(topics);
}
```

Then, in run method you can consume each kafka message as shared below.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        while (!flagOfThread) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, byte []> records = consumer.poll(10000);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, byte []> record : records) {
                handleRecord(record);
            }
            // At least one
            consumer.commitSync();
        }
    } catch (WakeupException e) {
        // Ignore exception if closing
        if (!flagOfThread){
            LOG.error("Log Consumer is shutting down.",e);
        }

    } finally {
        consumer.close();
    }
}
```

In your application runner class, you should create a threadpool, this **thread pool count must be equal to topic partition count** .

```
 ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(parallelismCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < parallelismCount; i++) {
        ExecutionLogConsumer bean = new LogConsumer(/*parameters*/);
        executorService.execute(bean);
    }
```

Now you can start to consume your messages from kafka :)